# Payment gateway wants the secret key in javascript. I'm concerned about the key security here

Tags: javascript, java, api, security, razorpay

I'm using razorpay as a payment gateway for the website that I've been working on. The gateway api needs a secret key which according to the documentation, I need to put it in my javascript call. This is okay for dev environment but I'm highly skeptical about putting production key in JS as it can be abused in many ways. 
What would be the ideal way of handling this scenario? Should I send keys from backend (java) which are encoded (doesn't seem right)?

Answer (score 2):

There are two entities. One is secret and other is the key.

Key needs to be passed in the script to create razorpay payment form. There is no issue in that.

For all the transactions to razorpay which demands secret, you should make your own APIs on your server. Never put it in client-side javascript.

For example, when creating an order, you will need to pass the secret. So, make an api where you can pass the reference number from your system and get back the order_id from razorpay. Do all the operations to razorpay on server side code. This way secret will not be exposed to the end user.